# Angular Dynamic Component Loading from JSON (API)

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am trying to load components dynamically from the response of an API Call.

Lets say I have 3 components/widgets A, B and C. Depending on the response of the API call, I have to load either A, B, C or any combination of them in any order (like load them in the order of C and then B). Somewhat like a CMS on the client side.

The one solution I thought of was using getting HTML code with ids of components from the API and using [innerHtml].

Are there any alternative solutions where I can get a list of widget/component from API, and load them in Angular Dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought of was using getting HTML code with ids of components from
> the API and using [innerHtml]

Why don't you use content-projection for such things instead of creating multiple component. Create one component and pass the `html` using `ng-content` in the child component. You can check [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/) for more details.

> here any alternative solutions where I can get a list of
> widget/component from API, and load them in Angular Dynamically?

You can use `ComponentFactoryResolver`  from angular which will help you to get it done. You need to get `viewContainerRef` and using the `ComponentFactoryResolver` create a component dynamically and inject it.

[This](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) is a good reference you can follow to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called "ComponentFactoryResolver". Hope this will help you on your case.

For more details:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components